# How to set onClick on cards in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, onclick, adapter

I have implemented a recycler view with cards and I would like to implement onClick functions on each of the cards. Basically I have two classes, which is the MainActivity as well as the RVAdapter class.

This is how i implement the onclick function inside the Adapter class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ShopViewHolder shopViewHolder, final int i) {
    shopViewHolder.shopNameTV.setText(shops.get(i).name);
    shopViewHolder.categoryTV.setText(shops.get(i).category);
    shopViewHolder.phoneNumberTV.setText(shops.get(i).phoneNumber);
    shopViewHolder.ratingsTV.setText(shops.get(i).ratings);
    shopViewHolder.emailTV.setText(shops.get(i).email);

    final Shop shop = shops.get(i);
    shopViewHolder.shopNameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.d("test","onclickk here" + i);
        }
    }) ;
}
```

In my xml file which contains the cards:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:onClick="onBindViewHolder"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/shopnameTV"
        />
```

However, the problem is that when I click on the cards, It will lead me to the error saying that onBindViewHolder is not in the main activity class.

How do I solve this error ? Or how do I pass the variables to the RVAdapter class instead of the Main activity class after onClick?

Answer (score 0):

The android:onClick property only works when the the named method exists in the Activity that's hosting the view.  So in your case, Android is going to look for a method *on the Activity* with this signature to handle the click:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(View v)
```

The error you're seeing indicates that Android can't find this method.

Instead, remove the onClick property from the view XML and registering a click listener on the card view itself, similar to what you're doing with shopViewHolder.shopNameTV.